# Convert latitude and longitude into esri arcGIS MapPoint

Tags: android, gps, arcgis, esri

I am having trouble in converting the latitude and longitude values into android esri arcGIS map Point. Here's my code to get latitude and longitude values from GPS coordinates:

```
LocationManager lm;
String towers;
double lat;
double longi;
TextView txt;

            lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Criteria crit = new Criteria();
            towers = lm.getBestProvider(crit, false);
            Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(towers);

            if(location != null)
            {
                lat = location.getLatitude();
                longi = location.getLongitude();
            }
```

now I have the latitude and longitude values. Now all I need is to convert these values into valid esri arcGIS MapPoint. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you're using the ESRI Android API? If so, create a graphics layer on your map. Then create a point object

```
com.esri.core.geometry.Point
Point myPoint = new Point();
```

then set the x/y values:

```
myPoint.setX(longi);
myPoint.setY(lat);
```

then add myPoint to the graphics object.

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgismobile/10.0/apis/android/api/index.html

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is possible. But you don't use the locationmanager in ArcGis.

ArcGIS has the predefined method like LocationListener, that is: **OnStatusChangedListener.**

See the below code for converting location latitude and longitude into esri arcGIS MapPoint.

```
     mMapView.setOnStatusChangedListener(new OnStatusChangedListener() {

            /**
             * 
             */
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      public void onStatusChanged(Object source, STATUS status) {
      if (source == mMapView && status == STATUS.INITIALIZED) {
      LocationService ls = mMapView.getLocationService();
      ls.setAutoPan(false);
      ls.setLocationListener(new LocationListener() {

      boolean locationChanged = false;

      // Zooms to the current location when first GPS fix
      // arrives.
      public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
      if (!locationChanged) {
      locationChanged = true;
      double locy = loc.getLatitude();
      double locx = loc.getLongitude();
      Point wgspoint = new Point(locx, locy);
      Point mapPoint = (Point) GeometryEngine.project(wgspoint,  

      SpatialReference.create(4326),

      mMapView.getSpatialReference());

      Unit mapUnit = mMapView.getSpatialReference().getUnit();
      double zoomWidth = Unit.convertUnits(

      SEARCH_RADIUS, Unit.create(LinearUnit.Code.MILE_US), mapUnit);
      Envelope zoomExtent = new Envelope(mapPoint, zoomWidth, zoomWidth);

      mMapView.setExtent(zoomExtent);

      GraphicsLayer gLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
      PictureMarkerSymbol symbol = new     
      PictureMarkerSymbol(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.twiz_car_red));
      Graphic graphic = new Graphic(mapPoint, symbol);
      //Graphic point=new Graphic(new Point(x, y),new    
      SimpleMarkerSymbol(Color.CYAN,20,STYLE.CIRCLE));   
      gLayer.addGraphic(graphic);
      mMapView .addLayer(gLayer);

         }
      }

      public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {

            }
      public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
            }

      public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1,
      Bundle arg2) {

         }
        });
      ls.start();

     }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

I've borrowed some code from [here](http://www.gal-systems.com/2011/07/convert-coordinates-between-web.html)

```
private Point ToGeographic(Point pnt)
{
    double mercatorX_lon = pnt.getX();
    double mercatorY_lat = pnt.getY();
    if (Math.abs(mercatorX_lon) < 180 && Math.abs(mercatorY_lat) < 90)
        return pnt;

    if ((Math.abs(mercatorX_lon) > 20037508.3427892) || (Math.abs(mercatorY_lat) > 20037508.3427892))
        return pnt;

    double x = mercatorX_lon;
    double y = mercatorY_lat;
    double num3 = x / 6378137.0;
    double num4 = num3 * 57.295779513082323;
    double num5 = Math.floor((double)((num4 + 180.0) / 360.0));
    double num6 = num4 - (num5 * 360.0);
    double num7 = 1.5707963267948966 - (2.0 * Math.atan(Math.exp((-1.0 * y) / 6378137.0)));
    mercatorX_lon = num6;
    mercatorY_lat = num7 * 57.295779513082323;
    return new Point(mercatorX_lon, mercatorY_lat);
}

private Point ToWebMercator(Point pnt)
{
    double mercatorX_lon = pnt.getX();
    double mercatorY_lat = pnt.getY();
    if ((Math.abs(mercatorX_lon) > 180 || Math.abs(mercatorY_lat) > 90))
        return pnt;

    double num = mercatorX_lon * 0.017453292519943295;
    double x = 6378137.0 * num;
    double a = mercatorY_lat * 0.017453292519943295;

    mercatorX_lon = x;
    mercatorY_lat = 3189068.5 * Math.log((1.0 + Math.sin(a)) / (1.0 - Math.sin(a)));
    return new Point(mercatorX_lon, mercatorY_lat);
}
```

I make no claims of efficiency, but it's a starting point at least.

Comment: really sooooooooooooooooooooo awesome

Answer (score 4):

**Disclaimer:** I'm not an expert in this, but want to try to help. :)

There is now an [ArcGIS Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) site. There's more information being added all the time and is a nice consolidated resource compared to what is out there disbursed on the interwebs.

For frameworks, I recommend [GeoTools](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GEOTOOLS/Android) for Android.

As an aside, [QGIS for Android](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/android-qgis) is an interesting project from Marco Bernasocchi which you may find helpful as a reference.

Hope you can find what you're looking for!

Answer (score 4):

i made a function that converts the two parameters of a location point to arcgis point :

```
private Point ConvertMyLocationPoint(final double x, final double y) {
        Point wgspoint = new Point(x, y);
        Point mapPoint = (Point) GeometryEngine.project(wgspoint, SpatialReference.create(4326),
                mMapView.getSpatialReference());

        return mapPoint;    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

//convert longitude and latitude to map point X Y

```
- (AGSPoint *)agsPointFromLatitude:(double)latitude longitude:(double)longitude
  {
      double mercatorX = longitude * 0.017453292519943295 * 6378137.0;
     double a = latitude * 0.017453292519943295;
      double mercatorY = 3189068.5 * log((1.0 + sin(a))/(1.0 - sin(a)));
      AGSPoint *obj = [AGSPoint pointWithX:mercatorX y:mercatorY spatialReference:    [AGSSpatialReference   wgs84SpatialReference]];


          return obj;
  }
```