# Android ESRI SDK map could not update the active symbol

Tags: android, dictionary, arcgis, esri

I am using ESRI Android SDK with OneMap server from Singapore as the basemap. 
When I start the map's location service, the accuracy circle is causing an exception due to invalid SpatialReference.

```
Could not update the active symbol
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid SpatialReference.
at com.esri.core.geometry.SpatialReference.nativeGetUnit(Native Method)
at com.esri.core.geometry.SpatialReference.getUnit(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.android.map.LocationService$a.k(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.android.map.LocationService$a$a.onLocationChanged(Unknown Source)
```

My code is as follows

```
map = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.map);

basemap = new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer
            ("http://e1.onemap.sg/arcgis/rest/services/SM128/MapServer");

map.addLayer(basemap);

map.setOnStatusChangedListener(new OnStatusChangedListener()
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(Object source, STATUS status) {
        if (OnStatusChangedListener.STATUS.INITIALIZED == 
                            status && source == map) 
         { 

            //Start location service
            LocationService ls = map.getLocationService();

            ls.setLocationListener(new LocationListener(){

                 @Override
                 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                                 // Do something                            

                            }

                 @Override
                 public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            }

                 @Override
                 public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            }

                 @Override
                 public void onStatusChanged(String provider,
                                    int status, Bundle extras) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            }

                   });

                   ls.start();
        }

}
```

This problem does not occur when the accuracy circle is disabled but in my case I would require it to be enabled.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there might be a problem with SpatialReference.getUnit when using a custom spatial reference, as [your map service](http://e1.onemap.sg/arcgis/rest/services/SM128/MapServer) does. You might want to report it to Esri support, because it looks like something they need to fix.

Meanwhile, there are two possible workarounds:

- Before adding the `ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer`, add a `GraphicsLayer` with spatial reference 3414. That should get the MapView's spatial reference to be 3414 so that the `LocationService` can start.
- Publish your service in a well-known spatial reference. It looks like you're trying for [3414](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3414/), so maybe use that in the map document you're publishing instead of using the custom SR you're using now.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it led me to the source of the problem. However I do not own the map service so there is nothing I can do to change it's spatial reference.

Comment: Try adding a GraphicsLayer with spatial reference 3414. See edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

All geometries in the map must be in the same coordinate system (SpatialReference). Try projecting (use GeometryEngine class) the location coordinates to the same spatialreference as your basemap.
Check one of the comments here that does it 
[Convert latitude and longitude into esri arcGIS MapPoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803726/convert-latitude-and-longitude-into-esri-arcgis-mappoint)