# how to show longitude and latitude points in offline map arcgis in android?

Tags: android, arcgis

in my app I have my own offline map (.tpk) but now I want to show some points on my map and I have some `longitude` and `latitude` , I am using this code :

```
            double locy = 44.008655;
            double locx = 36.1972958;
            Point wgspoint = new Point(locx, locy);
            Point mapPoint = (Point) GeometryEngine.project(wgspoint,

            SpatialReference.create(4326),

            mMapView.getSpatialReference());

            GraphicsLayer gLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
            PictureMarkerSymbol symbol = new PictureMarkerSymbol(getResources()
                    .getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
            Graphic graphic = new Graphic(mapPoint, symbol);
            gLayer.addGraphic(graphic);
            mMapView.addLayer(gLayer);
```

to show locy and locx but nothing happened , this code is correct to show points ?
or there is another way to do this ? thanks for any help....

Comment: Are your coordinates the right way around? [E 36.1972958, N 44.008655](http://goo.gl/maps/5mDj9) (as you've got it) is somewhere in the Black Sea, while [E 44.008655, N 36.1972958](http://goo.gl/maps/sYiFS) is in northern Iraq... I'm not saying the Black Sea isn't interesting, just that I'm not sure why you'd be putting a point there. :)

Comment: yeah of course am in nothern Iraq that's right but , please tell me , this is wrong or not ? this is the only way to add points to offline map

Comment: It looks ok to me (I'm not an expert on the Android API though), but if your map is centered in northern Iraq then you're not going to see any points there because they're all in the Black Sea. So your code may be working, it's just not doing what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to convert the points of longitudes and the latitudes to the accepted esri arcGIS MapPoint
in this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18201839/1905122) you can find your answer

Comment: Looks like that answer and @ROR have copied the same example, since the code's almost identical.

Comment: @Juffy this answer soooooooooooooooooooo perfect , look we have to choose the best answer , that will help the other users , don't complain , this is the right answer BTW .

Comment: I'm not complaining, I just couldn't see what the linked answer did that you weren't already doing - your code and Hareesh's look almost identical. If it works then everyone's happy, but I'm certainly none the wiser. :)